# How and where do I access statusCallBackEvent data in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

This is probably a very novice question...
So, Twilio doc says it will send statusCallBackEvent data to URL specified in status_callback on specified events.

How and where do I access this data? Does this mean Twilio will create & write a file to the provided URL?

I want to be able to get this data real time so that I can execute certain code in Python based on the event information.

For example, once it's ringing, I want to be notified and execute certain code.

```
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'your_auth_token'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                        method='GET',
                        status_callback='https://www.myapp.com/events',
                        status_callback_event=['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered'],
                        status_callback_method='POST',
                        url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                        to='+14155551212',
                        from_='+18668675310'
                    )

print(call.sid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio can POST or GET the data over to the URL you provide, i.e. `https://www.myapp.com/events`. You can use a tool like [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)to view the data sent to your application by looking at the debug URL, http://127.0.0.1:4040/. You will need a web framework like Flask, to consume this information, extract the information and run your Python code. You can take a look at [TwilioQuest Starter code for Python](https://github.com/twilio/starter-python) and the Twilio Python blogs below for for insight. You will also want to take a look at [TwilioQuest](https://www.twilio.com/quest).

[Twilio Blogs on Flask](https://www.twilio.com/blog/search?q=Flask)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to incorporate Flask to run my app. Do I need an html or php page in order to fetch the StatusCallBackEvent data?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could take a look at my new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63776883/statuscallbackevent-in-twilio-returns-none